# Error Php 8.0 Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, bool given

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Recently the host provider updated php to 8.0 and in my post the next fatal error appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type
> Countable|array, bool given in line 78,

This is the line 78 code:

```
if(count(get_field('news_detail_related_posts', $post->ID)) > 0): ?
```

Any options to solve this? I searched and tried two options but they were not working.

Comment: It looks like the `get_field` function returns `true` or `false` (i.e. `bool` values), rather than something you can count. It is possible for it to return various types - see the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/). So you need to make sure you only try to count things which you actually expect to be countable things, such as arrays. If you can't be sure whether the field will have a value, you should check it before passing it to the count() function.

Comment: Thanks but the site had the function to show the related posts if one is selected, but when is not selected o chose a related one marks error. But this not happened before

Comment: That's because in earlier versions of php it was only generating a warning, not a fatal error. So, as I said, you now need to make it so that it checks if get_field returns an array before attempting to count that result

Comment: Thanks for your time, it's solve only added is_countable('news_detail_related_posts') && count(get_field('news_detail_related_posts' and the error dissapear

Comment: it looks like you have a condition inside the `count` function, can you please provide the whole code and explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you've solved your own problem please consider making an answer to your own question and accepting it so that future users looking for a solution can find it more easily without having to look through comments.